# Updating value inside json data PSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I have a table that contains tables stores in data column as a JSON using psql, 
trying to update specific cell in the (data column) which is array of objects.

for example, updating the "first_name":"Fergus" to "first_name":"Marcus" where "id":"1"

```
CREATE TABLE tables(
    table_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    table_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    user_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    data json
);

INSERT INTO tables (table_name, user_id, data)
VALUES (
'Supplier Info', 4, '[
{"id":"1","first_name":"Fergus","last_name":"Flipsen","email":"fflipsen0@ezinearticles.com","gender":"Male"},
 {"id":"2","first_name":"Vincenz","last_name":"Russan","email":"vrussan1@independent.co.uk","gender":"Male"}
]'::JSON);
```

Comment: This would be sooo much easier with a properly normalized model

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy (and, as commented by a_horse_with_no_name, it would be much simpler with a normalized schema).

Basically, you need to unnest the inner array, modify the relevant object, then aggregate back into an array.

You can do this with a correlated subquery, `jsonb_array_elements()` and conditional logic in `jsonb_agg()`:

```
update tables t
set data = (
    select 
        jsonb_agg(
            case when (x.obj ->> 'id')::int = 1 
                then x.obj || '{"first_name": "Marcus"}'
                else x.obj
            end
            order by x.ord
        ) new_data
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.data) with ordinality x(obj, ord)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=15b1c401c32a773936d490f9ea1b3265)**

Comment: thank you GMB! worked for me (works on jsonb datatype and not json) but great.
Anyway, sure ill be working on doing the db normalized. 
Thanks alot.

Comment: when sending the query, i receive invalid input syntax for type json:
length: 152,
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: 'Token "$" is invalid.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: '120',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: 'JSON data, line 1: {$...',
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'json.c',
  line: '1244',
  routine: 'report_invalid_token' } 'this is the err'

Comment: @MoradAbed: the problem is with your data, which contains invlid JSON.